# Print text between two patterns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to:

> Print text between "hi" and "hello" patterns.

Patterns may be repeated and there may be multiple occurrences of `hi`..`hello`.

Source file:

```
hi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello xxxxxx
aaaa dddd cccc hi aaa bbb
ccc hello cccc fff
```

Expected output.

```
hi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello
hi aaa bbb
ccc hello
```

I tried with `awk` and `sed -n` commands whereas it displays all the line between the first occurrence of `hi` and the last occurrence of `hello`.

Comment: You need to post bigger example of input file and expected output including multi-blocks.

Comment: Also show how a file with multiple `hi`/`hello` (on the same line and on consecutive lines) should be treated.

Answer (score 2):

From the **first** hi to the **first** hello that follows.

## grep

Using (GNU) grep and tr:

```
$ <infile grep -oPz "(?s)hi.*?hello" | tr '\0' '\n'
hi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello
hi aaa bbb
ccc hello
```

Descripttion:

- `<infile` Source file.
- `grep -oPz`  Call `grep` to:

  - (`-P`) match a [**P**CRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (Perl Compatible Regular Expression)
  - (`-o`) **o**nly print the matching part.
  - (`-z`) use a **z**ero byte (a.k.a. NUL and a.k.a. `\0`) as line delimiter.
- `"(?s)` Make the PCRE dot (`.`) match also newlines.
- `hi` Starting with the string `hi`.
- `.*?` Match all characters that follow (non-greedy because of `?`).
- `hello"` Up until the string `hello` is matched.
- `| tr '\0' '\n'` Convert the NULs (`\0`) bytes (from `grep -z`) to newlines.

## sed

GNU sed:

```
<infile sed 's/hi/\n&/;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\(hello\).*/\1/;/hi/,/hello/!d'
```

Or, for BSD sed, which doesn't allow `\n` on the right side of `s///`, you need to define a `newline` variable `nl`:

```
$ eval "$(printf "nl='\n'")"
```

And, then:

```
<infile sed 's/hi/\'"$nl"'&/;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\(hello\).*/\1/;/hi/,/hello/!d'
```

Or; if you could write an explicit newline:

```
<infile sed 's/hi/\
&/;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\(hello\).*/\1/;/hi/,/hello/!d'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion, i tried with below command and it worked, but its adding letter n before hi, also its taking the complete line of the start pattern, below is the o/p i got

Comment: nhi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello
aaaa dddd cccc nhi aaa bbb
ccc hello

Comment: command i tried infile sed 's/hi/\n&/;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\(hello\).*/\1/;/hi/,/hello/!d'

Comment: Then, you have a BSD sed, which doesn't allow a `\n` on the Right side of `s///`. Use the BSD version(s). @user314870

Comment: You don't need the `tr` part. Grep isn't replacing `\n` with `\0` because of `-z` (try it!), it's just looking for lines separated by `\0` instead of `\n`, which in most cases allows to look at the whole file as a single line. The `\n` characters remain untouched, though.

Comment: No, @BenjaminW. the `tr` is there not to recover any `\n`. Yes, the **existing** `\n` pass tru all right. The `tr` is there to have an ending `hello` in one line and the next `hi` in another line. If that is not a problem that you need solving (and you don't care about the output having some `\0` bytes) then don't use that part.

Comment: Oh, I get it know, you're right! I ignored that there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oPz "(?s)hi.*?hello" fileName
```

Explanation below.

cat tmp

Output ->

```
hi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello xxxxxx
aaaa dddd cccc hi aaa bbb
ccc hello cccc fff
00000000000
hi ff 
djd h
sdkf hello
dfj
```

**Solution:**

```
grep -oPz "(?s)hi.*?hello" tmp
```

Output ->

```
hi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello
hi aaa bbb
ccc hello
hi ff 
djd h
sdkf hello
```

Params:

- `-z` this option tells grep to treat newlines as ordinary text characters, and look for null bytes to separate records.  In a text file with no null bytes, `grep -z` will treat the entire file as one line.
- `(?s)` activate PCRE_DOTALL, which means that '.' finds any character or newline.
- `o` Only print the matched part
- `-P`
  Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE). This is highly experimental, particularly when combined with the -z (--null-data) option, and ‘grep -P’ may warn of unimplemented features.
- `.*?` For non-greedy match. Start searching for next match of `hi` when you find first instance of `hello`

  Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: The grep `-z` output will include some `\0` (not newlines). Those have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

awk for giggles

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    n=split($0, col, FS)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        (i==n)? sp="" : sp=FS
        if (col[i] ~ /hi/) p=1
        if (p == 1  && col[i] ~ /hello/) h=1
        if (p == 1) printf("%s%s",col[i],sp)
        if (h==1) p=0;h=0
    }
    printf "\n"
}



kapu@jake:$ cat SourceFile
hi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello xxxxxx
aaaa dddd cccc hi aaa bbb
ccc hello cccc fff
kapu@jake:$ script.awk SourceFile
hi aa bb cc
dd ee ff
hello
hi aaa bbb
ccc hello
```